# Is it possible to make a Close/Dismiss button for HTML native <dialog> (no plugin) with <form>?

Tags: javascript, html, dialog

Following this [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog#examples), I create a simple `dialog` that contains a `form`:

```js
const diag = document.querySelector("#diag")

diag.addEventListener("close", () => {
  if (!diag.returnValue) { return; }
  
  document.querySelector(".result").textContent = document.querySelector("#txt-name").value;
});

document.querySelector("#btn-show").addEventListener("click", () => {
  diag.showModal();
});
```

```html
<dialog id="diag">
  <form method="dialog">
    <input id="txt-name" required />
    
    <button value="submit">Submit</button>
    <button value="">Cancel</button>
  </form>
</dialog>

<button id="btn-show">Show Dialog</button>

<p>Result: <span class="result"></span></p>
```

However since the `input` has `required` attribute, user cannot click it without filling it. I know I can add a `click` event to Cancel button and close the dialog but I have many dialogs like this and it's better if there is a general native solution.

I need a solution that closes the dialog; and sets its `returnValue` to empty ("") **if** `close` event is raised by such button.

Current workaround:

```js
document.querySelector("#btn-cancel")
   .addEventListener("click", () => {
      diag.close(""); // Have to set this since onclose event is raised.
   })
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear for me what you actually want to achieve. What is your desired end result ?

Comment: @MihaiT sorry I updated the question to include what I want and current workaround.

Comment: The closing of the dialog happens, _because_ the form gets submitted. But making the input field required, prevents the form submission from happening when the field did not get filled - and so the dialog does not close either. You will have to involve JS here for the functionality you want.

Comment: @CBroe yeah I understand that. I know why it is happening. I just wonder if there is a workaround I didn't know. Thanks.

Comment: Be careful! [Dialog is not fully supported on Firefox](https://caniuse.com/dialog).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The more appropriate way to make a close button would be to use `formnovalidate` attribute on the button/input element.

```js
const diag = document.querySelector("#diag")

diag.addEventListener("close", () => {
  if (!diag.returnValue) { return; }
  
  document.querySelector(".result").textContent = document.querySelector("#txt-name").value;
});

document.querySelector("#btn-show").addEventListener("click", () => {
  diag.showModal();
});
```

```html
<dialog id="diag">
  <form method="dialog">
    <input id="txt-name" required />
    
    <button value="submit">Submit</button>
    <button value="" formnovalidate>Cancel</button>
  </form>
</dialog>

<button id="btn-show">Show Dialog</button>

<p>Result: <span class="result"></span></p>
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't know this did it. Can confirm it work (I edited your answer because you had a typo, and moved it into a HTML code block).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using `dialog.close()` in your `cancel button` event listener.
Doing so will discard all of the dialog and thus get rid of all unfilled `inputs`.
The form will **not** get submitted on `dialog.close()`.